# how to keep gunicorn flask app running after ssh aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, gunicorn

I am new to server and apps.

Currently, I have created an app on my aws instance.

```
gunicorn --threads 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile server.log --timeout 60 server:app
```

But I want to keep it running after I ssh the instance, how could I achieve this?

```
[2018-09-24 17:45:28 +0000] [8318] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-09-24 17:45:28 +0000] [8318] [INFO] Listening at: 
 http://0.0.0.0:5000 (8318)
[2018-09-24 17:45:28 +0000] [8318] [INFO] Using worker: threads
[2018-09-24 17:45:28 +0000] [8321] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8321
```

I have to use control+c to exit too at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add --daemon to your command line or use screen (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)